# Python pattern looping

Tags: python

I'm having trouble on printing alternate pattern, the output is suppose to look like this:

```
input height: 7

22
1122
221122
11221122
2211221122
112211221122
22112211221122
```

But instead it came out like this:

```
input height: 7
22
1111
222222
11111111
2222222222
111111111111
22222222222222
```

Code:

```
height = int (input ("input height: "))

for level in range (1, height+1):
    num = level

    for x in range (num):
        if( level%2==0): #Even row starts with "11" first
            print ("11",end = "")
        else:
            print ("22",end = "")
    print()
```

By using looping, while, for loop, no list. How can I do this?

Comment: `2*level - level` ? isn't that `= level` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everything inside your `x` loop, `level` never changes. You need to alternate based on `x` while choosing your start based on `level`.

```
height = int (input ("input height: "))

for level in range (1, height+1):
    num = level

    for x in range (num):
        if( (level+x)%2==0): #Even row starts with "11" first
            print ("11",end = "")
        else:
            print ("22",end = "")
    print()
```

Notice how I add `level` and `x` before modding it against 2.

Comment: @Chloe no problem. You were very close :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not coming out like you want it, because you are choosing to use only one type of fill character per line with `if(level%2==0):`.

It looks like you need to figure out how to switch between two different fill values on each line. I suggest that:

1. You accumulate to a string for each line before printing
2. You look into how you can use a sequence (list or tuple) to cycle through values. There's also a tool in `itertools` you could use.

Answer (score 2):

You could add to the string each iteration by inserting new characters from the left:

```
s = ""
for i in range(height):
    s = ('22', '11')[i % 2] + s
    print(s)
```

Or just build the whole string each iteration:

```
for i in range(height):
    print ''.join(('11', '22')[j % 2] for j in range(i + 1, 0, -1))
```

Or precompute the last row and slice it from the right:

```
s = '1122' * (height / 2 + 1)
for i in range(height):
    print s[(i+1) * -2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if( level%2==0): #Even row starts with "11" first
```

to

```
if( (level+x) %2==0): #Even row starts with "11" first
```

Python 2.7:

```
for level in range(1,height+1):
     for x in range(level):                                                   
        if((level+x)%2==0):                                                  
            print "11",                                                      
        else:                                                                
            print "22",
```

Comment: edited, Brian beat me too it, and I forgot to alternate the start for x.

Answer (score 0):

```
height = int (input ("input height: "))

for level in range (1, height+1):
   # Starting at level gives the proper oddity, while 2* level give the proper loop length
    for x in range (level, 2 * level):
        if( x%2==0): #Even row starts with "11" first
            print ("11",end="")
        else:
            print ("22",end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = "1122" * height
for tail in range(1, height+1):
    print tmp[-2*tail:]
```

done